# How to Split a String in Order to Create a Duplicate Row and Count Values in BigQuery

Tags: sql, join, split, google-bigquery, count

For the record I'm fairly new to SQL and still learning as I go.

I have a table that has a list of video game titles and their respective platform. Some of the titles were released on 2 platforms, and the record has both platforms within the `Platform` column delimited by " / " .

Essentially I am trying to create a query that counts the number of titles per platform, but I want titles that been released on two different platforms to be counted separately for their respective platform.

**What I Have**

| Platform | Number_of_Games |
| --- | --- |
| Nintendo Switch | 4 |
| PS3/Xbox 360 | 1 |
| PS4/Windows | 1 |
| Wii U/ Nintendo Switch | 3 |
| Xbox 360 | 1 |

**What I Want**

| Platform | Number_of_Games |
| --- | --- |
| Nintendo Switch | 7 |
| PS3 | 1 |
| PS4 | 1 |
| Wii U | 3 |
| Windows | 1 |
| Xbox 360 | 2 |

*There are more platforms that are similar, but I shorten list for my question.

I've tried using `SPLIT` with and without `[offset(0)]` , making a temp table using `UNION ALL`, Joining the original table for the `COUNT`, and then `GROUP BY` and could not get it to work properly. I also tried not using `[offset(0)]`, but that does not produce what I am looking for.

At the very basics, I have:

```
SELECT SPLIT(Platform,"/") [offset(0)] AS Platform, Count(Title) AS Number_of_Games
  FROM `VideoGames`
  GROUP BY Platform
```

However, this only shows the values before the **"/"** and does not take the others in for the count.

I've also tried:

```
With Platforms AS 
  (
    SELECT "Wii U" AS Platform
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Nintendo Switch" AS Platform
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Xbox 360" AS Platform
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT "PS3" AS Platform
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "PS4" AS Platform
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Windows" AS Platform
)
    
SELECT SPLIT(Top50.Platform,"/") [offset(0)]  AS Platform,Count(Top50.Title) AS Number_of_Games
  FROM `VideoGames` AS Top50 
LEFT JOIN Platforms AS P
  ON Top50.Platform=P.Platform
  GROUP BY Platform
```

However, this does the same. I also did `FULL JOIN` and I *believe* it shows the split values after the **" / "**, but it does not count correctly and it appears that Windows is showing up as null in the Platform column.

At this point, I am stuck and not sure how to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: which database system exactly are you using

Comment: Try something like `case when platform like '%Switch%' then 'Nintendo Switch' else platform`.

Comment: Hi @nbk, the data I'm using is  from Kagggle. However, I did do my own cleaning of it. Here is the link https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/devrimtuner/top-100-video-games

Comment: Hi @Andrew! This seems to be almost working! However, when using CASE on for example "PS4/Windows", the query result will only show "PS4" or "Windows" based on its placement in the code; it will not show both since I guess the latter does not exist anymore?  Any idea on how to combat this?

Comment: @mlooch97 we don't need the data , we need to know which database system like mysql postgres sql server oracle or or or  you are using

Comment: @nbk my apologies, I am using BigQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider below.

```sql
WITH VideoGames AS (
  SELECT 'Nintendo Switch' Platform, 4 Number_of_Games UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PS3/Xbox 360', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PS4/Windows', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Wii U/ Nintendo Switch', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Xbox 360', 1
)
SELECT TRIM(split_platform) Platform, SUM(Number_of_Games) Number_of_Games
  FROM VideoGames, UNNEST(SPLIT(Platform, '/')) split_platform
 GROUP BY 1;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jaytiger, Thank you so for your response! With this, I replaced the UNION ALL section with "SELECT Platform, COUNT(Title) AS Number_of_Games... GROUP BY Platform", and this produced exactly what I was looking for! However in your example, how does "Group BY 1" work?

Comment: `Group by 1` groups rows together based on 1st column value. In this case, it will be `TRIM(split_platform)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it too complicated

First SPLIT the table into rows and keep the numbers, then sum it up

```
WITH CTE as (SELECT Platform, COUNT(Title)Number_of_Games
  FROM `VideoGames`
  GROUP BY Platform
  ),CTE2 as
  (SELECT SPLIT( ,"/") as platform,Number_of_Games),
  CTE3 AS (
  SELECT
r,Number_of_Games
FROM CTE2,
UNNEST(r) r)
  SELECT r as Pattform, SUM(Number_of_Games) Number_of_Games
  FROM CTE3
  GROUP BY r
```

Comment: Hi @nbk, thank you very much for your help and answer! However, "Number_of_Games is actually an alias for "Count(Title)", and Title is a String. When doing this, I would have to CAST "Title" to a different schema, but I do not think that works properly.  Ultimately, I swapped Sum to "Count(Title)", but  it leaves me with an error "Grouping by expressions of type ARRAY is not allowed"

Comment: i have changed the query

Comment: My apologies, this was also an edit I attempted, which still leads to the "Grouping by expressions of type ARRAY is not allowed" error. I believe this is why I originally attempted to use UNION ALL and JOIN because it allowed me to bypass the error, but I could not get it to work properly.

Comment: then we need another step between see now

Comment: same error at the end :( . Could this be BigQuery related?

Comment: @mlooch97 no it is because split returns an array, so we to unnest it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252427/discussion-between-mlooch97-and-nbk).